# iterate through string and combine the previous characters in each loop

Tags: c++, loops

In the string "61C99161" I want to iterate through each character and combine the previous looped characters. For example in this code:

```
string hex = "61C99161";

for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < hex.size(); ++i) {

    cout<<hex[i]<<endl;
}
```

It prints:

```
6
1
C
9
```

...and so on. But how can I print the following?

```
6
61
61C
61C9
```

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few possibilities. One obvious one would be something like:

```
for (i=0; i<hex.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << hex.substr(0, i) << "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, one more question, what if the string was in an array? e.g std::string hex[2] = { "61C99161","g53fb4h6" };

Comment: @Znap: putting the string into an array doesn't really change much. It's still a string, so you can still do all the normal string things with it.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a variation to the mix:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != hex.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout.write(hex.data(), i + 1);
    std::cout.put('\n');
}
```

Comment: I was thinking it was start index... but you are right!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string hex = "61C99161";
  std::ostringstream ss;
  for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < hex.size(); ++i) {
    ss << hex[i];
    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

If you have an array of `std::string`s:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  unsigned const S = 2;  // No magic constants...
  std::string hex[S] = {"61C99161", "g53fb4h6"};
  // I would rather use std::vector<std::string> by the way:
  // std::vector<std::string> hex{"61C99161", "g53fb4h6"};

  std::ostringstream ss;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < S; ++i) {
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < hex[i].size(); ++j) {
      ss << hex[i][j];
      std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
    }
    ss.str("");  // Remove this line if you want to concatenate all the words
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Im new to c++, I'll search what are the uses of the codes you added does

Comment: Very welcome. However, also consider the other answers - they might be easier to understand if you new to this language.

Comment: `std::string hex[2] = { "61C99161","g53fb4h6" };                 
        std::ostringstream ss;
 for (int o = 0; o < 2;o++){
 for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < hex[o].size(); ++i) {
  ss << hex[i];
  std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;}
 }
 system("pause");`

Comment: I added this modification to the answer but I think you should modify the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of where you are in the string, and write everything up to that point:

```
int main() {
    std::string hex = "61C99161";
    for (int offset =  1; offset < hex.size(); ++offset) {
        for (int i = 0; i < offset; ++i)
            std::cout << hex[i];
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you print a character, add it to a previouslyPrinted string, which will be printed before every character.

```
std::string previouslyPrinted="";
string hex = "61C99161";

for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < hex.size(); ++i) {

    cout<<previouslyPrinted<<hex[i]<<endl;
    previouslyPrinted+=hex[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

  string hex = "61C99161";

  for (int i=0; i<hex.size(); ++i)
    cout << hex.substr(0, i) << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other version could be simply using another `string` (`buffer`) to store the characters printed before as in the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string hex = "61C99161";
    string buffer;

    for (const char& c : hex) //Range-based for loop
    {
        std::cout << buffer << c << endl;
        buffer = buffer + c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```